# Extract hash or page

Tags: jquery, url, hash

I need to edit below code. Now it works well for anchors in url (www.mypage.com/#contact). I need to modify this code to save into the *var target* variable according to the following example:

www.mypage.com/#contact  > target = contact

www.mypage.com/page.html > target = page

www.mypage.com/page.html#contact > target = contact

```
$('a.js-scroll-trigger[href*="#"]').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 70)
        }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");
        return false;
      }
    }
});
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: what about:  `www.mypage.com` and `www.mypage.com/target` and `www.mypage.com/target/` and `www.mypage.com#` and `www.mypage.com/#` and `www.mypage.com/page.html#`?

Comment: so what's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my example below, I'm defining a variable that contains either the `hash` (without the "#") or the `pathname` (without file extension). Then, the resulting value is tested for whether an element exists with that `id` or `name`. If an element exists, scroll to it.

```js
$('a.js-scroll-trigger').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // get the hash (without #) or filename (without extension)
  var s = this.hash.substr(1) || this.pathname.match(/([^\/]+)(?=\.\w+$)/)[0];
  console.log(s);

  // test for an existing element that has matching ID or NAME.
  var $target = $("#" + s).length ? $("#" + s) : $('[name=' + s + ']');

  // if that element exists, scroll to it
  if ($target.length) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: ($target.offset().top - 70)
    }, 1000);
  }

});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}

#contents {
  margin-top: 150vh;
}

#contents div {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="https://www.mypage.com/#contact">www.mypage.com/#contact</a>
<a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="https://www.mypage.com/page.html">www.mypage.com/page.html</a>
<a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="https://www.mypage.com/page.html#contact">www.mypage.com/page.html#contact</a>

<div id="contents">
  <div id="contact">
    CONTACT
  </div>
  <div name="page">
    PAGE
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code and data-href i menu solved my problem.